# Stop after first match found (str_match)

Tags: regex, r, string

Is there an option to stop the search after the first "match" is found using str_match? Something equivalent to grep's "m"? I looked in stringr package, but couldnt find anything. Perhaps I missed it?

In a given string:

```
str <- "This is a 12-month study cycle"
```

I'm using the below to extract: 12-month from it

```
str_match(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ](month|months|week|weeks)")[1]
```

But if the string str extends to:

```
"This is a 12-month study cycle. In the 2 month period,blah blah...".
```

I'd like the search to just stop and retrieve 12-month and not get both: 12-month and 2-month. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?.. it can find anything with month/months/week/weeks for it?.. regardless of spaces and -?

Comment: Help us to help you, edit your question, it is hard to read, clarify your input and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this ?

```
str <- "This is a 12-month study cycle"    
regmatches(str, regexpr("(?i)(\\w+)[- ](month|months|week|weeks)", str) )
```

[1] "12-month"

```
str2 <- "This is a 12-month study cycle. In the 2 month period,blah blah..."
regmatches(str2, regexpr("(?i)(\\w+)[- ](month|months|week|weeks)", str2) )
```

[1] "12-month"

Answer (score 0):

Try `stringi` package. If you want to match all, use `stri_match_all_regex`, if just first or last use `stri_match_first_regex` or `stri_match_last_regex`.

```
    stri_match_first_regex(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ](month|months|week|weeks)")
     [,1]       [,2] [,3]   
[1,] "12-month" "12" "month"

 stri_match_all_regex(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ](month|months|week|weeks)")
[[1]]
     [,1]       [,2] [,3]   
[1,] "12-month" "12" "month"
[2,] "2 month"  "2"  "month"
```